# Global Search returns same result on a previous value. Bug?

Tags: global-search

Global Search still returns the same result for a modified data on the same account.
Assume I have an Account record "Tim". Tim has a custom field "Mobile_Phone__c".
At first Tim's mobile phone number was 123456789. Tim's number has changed to 0987654321.

When I search for 123456789, Tim's account is returned in Global Search results (even after a week the change has been made). Anyone experienced same behaviour?

Comment: Sometime the indexing takes couple of hours if you have large dataset, but a week is not expected. May be you can contact salesforce.